# SQL Sum showing statement instead of value on asp page

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to display the results of a simple SQL sum... I have the following SQL command on my .asp page using vb:

```
<%
  Dim QtyTotal
  QtyTotal = "SELECT SUM(Qty_SAL) FROM dbo.tbl_stock_at_locations"
  Response.Write(QtyTotal)
%>
```

The output (QtyTotal) is written as the SQL statement itself and not the value.

Comment: You need to bind model, this is a worst coding standard where you are querying from UI to DB

Comment: Exactly what part of that code do you think is executing anything against a database? All you're doing is creating a `String` and displaying it.

Comment: Are you sure you're using .Net? If it's just a *.asp page, rather than *.aspx, that's asp classic and vbscript (which, btw, hasn't seen any real maintenance as a platform in almost 20 years).

Comment: What you are doing is, saving some values into variable and displaying it to the screen. How you are executing the query?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this to connect to your database and to run your query.

```
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")  
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Qty_SAL) FROM dbo.tbl_stock_at_locations", con)  
con.Open()  
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()  
con.Close()
```

There are tons of articles out there on how to do this, please refer to google.com

Comment: The question was tagged poorly. It seems he's using asp classic.

Answer (score 0):

You have this value:

```
"SELECT SUM(Qty_SAL) FROM dbo.tbl_stock_at_locations"
```

That's just a string literal. Nothing more. Assigning it to `QtyTotal` just means the variable is a string with the SQL command text as it's value.

If you want to run the statement and get the result, you need to create an `ADO.Connection` object to the connect to a database server, create an `ADO.Command` object to hold your SQL statement, and associate the command with the connection. Then you can `.Open` the connection and `.Execute` the command to get an *object* back for reading results... the kind of object will depend on how you execute the command. Once you have this object, you have to actually *read from it* to assign the final value to `QtyTotal`.